# SQL removing part of delimited field based on joining match?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe there is a better method before I get to this step, but is there an easy way to match on one field, if it matches remove part of the match from a string in a second field.

TABLE example

```
ID   | ID LIST
-----|---------
ID07 |ID05;ID06;ID07;ID08
```

This is just a one record example so ID and ID LIST will vary. 
I'm looking to join and update/ replace the "nothing" or perhaps add a value to remove later.

```
Result I'm looking for
     ID  | ID LIST
    -----|---------
    ID07 |ID05;ID06;ID08
```

Is there any easy way to do this or should I go about this another way? I know some people would use a WHERE IN, but ID is going to vary. Maybe WHERE IN that field name. I'm a little confused conceptualizing this.

I'm using SQL Server MGMT studio.

Comment: A proper solution would be to fix your schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace function .. if id is in id_list is replaced with empty string

```
 select replace(ID_LIST, ID +';', '')
 from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET ID_LIST = CASE WHEN ID_LIST = ID THEN ''
                   WHEN ID_LIST LIKE ID + ';%' THEN SUBSTRING(ID_LIST, LEN(ID)+1, LEN(ID_LIST)-LEN(ID)-1)
                   WHEN ID_LIST LIKE '%;' + ID THEN LEFT(ID_LIST, LEN(ID_LIST)-LEN(ID)-1)
                   ELSE REPLACE(ID_LIST, ';'+ID+';', ';')
              END
WHERE ';'+ID_LIST+';' LIKE '%;'+ID+';%'
```